# how to add koush/UrlImageViewHelper in android project

Tags: android

I want to use this library https://github.com/koush/UrlImageViewHelper but I dont know how to add this library or integrate it with my project.

Answer (score 2):

Download as zip, unzip to folder, import projects into workspace, link projects in the android tab (right click project, properties, android tab, add library)